# How to solve for $q$ with modular exponentiation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve a modular equation to find an odd prime factor $q$ of $9276$ given that $9277$ is prime.

Here is what I have so far:

Choosing random base $b=3$,

$3^{9276}$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

$3^{4638}$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

$3^{2319}$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

$3^{2318}$ $=$ $6185 \pmod {9277}$

$q$ divides $2319$ so therefore,

$3^q$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

$3^{q-1}$ $=$ $6185 \pmod {9277}$

Now choosing $b=5$ to see if there is a different solution to:

$5^{2319}$ $=$ $8389 \pmod {9277}$

$8389^4$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

Then we have the following conclusion about $q$:

$8389^q$ $=$ $8389 \pmod {9277}$

$8389^{q-1}$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

$3^q$ $=$ $1 \pmod {9277}$

$3^{q-1}$ $=$ $6185 \pmod {9277}$

Can anyone help show me (all the work) how to find $q$ **without** factoring any numbers, based off the given information above? Thanks.

Comment: Certainly $q=3$ must be a prime divisor, because the sum of digits of $9276$ is divisible by three. Actually there is only one other odd prime divisor besides $q=3$. We could find it by Pollard rho algorithm.

Comment: The equations above do not hold for $q=3$, so $q$ is some other odd prime factor. $3$ is indeed a divisor of $9276$, but not the prime factor which makes the equation(s) true.